# Click group header to zoom out from zoom in view is not working in semantic zoom for windows 8.1 metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have used semantic zoom control in my universal app, the behaviour of semanic zoom works fine in windows phone 8.1 (click header to zoom out view from zoom in view and again click any item to come back to zoom in view), but it windows 8.1 metro i cannot go to zoom out view from zoom in view by clicking header but from zoom out i can go to zoom in view. i got many samples but every where i am facing the same problem, i dont know what mistake that i am doing, screenshot and my code is below.

Screenshot:

[[image: Zoom Out View]][2]
[image: Zoom In view]
Xaml code:

```
  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <SemanticZoom Name="MySemanticZoom" IsZoomedInViewActive="False" IsZoomOutButtonEnabled="True">
                <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                    <GridView x:Name="MySZ_ZoomedInGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollectionViewSource}}" 
                              SelectionChanged="MySZ_ZoomedInGridView_SelectionChanged"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" MinWidth="150" />
                                </StackPanel>                            
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <GridView.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" MinWidth="150">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Language}"  FontSize="22" Margin="10"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle>
                        </GridView.GroupStyle>
                    </GridView>
                </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                    <GridView x:Name="MySZ_ZoomedOutGridView" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Group.Language}"  FontSize="22" />
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="150">
                                            <TextBlock Text="No. Available:&#160;"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Group.Speakers.Count}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>  
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    </GridView>
                </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            </SemanticZoom>
            <Button Content="Click to change view" x:Name="ChangeViewButton" Click="ChangeViewButton_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Add items source to the gridview in zoomed out state and set it in this way:

```
<GridView x:Name="MySZ_ZoomedOutGridView" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollectionViewSource}, Path=CollectionGroups}">
```